# EF 5.x Code First Connection String for DbContext Not Working

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, mysql-connector

I have a Project that has EF code first Classes and DB context

```
public partial class MyProjectContext : DbContext
{
    public MyProjectContext()
        : base("name=MyProjectContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
```

My app.config looks like

```
<add name="MyProjectContext" connectionString="server=<serverIP>; user id=<userid>; password=<password>; database=<dbName>; pooling=false; Persist Security Info=True " providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

I have Reference to this Project1 above in my Web Project, I also have  connection string below in web project

```
<add name="MyProjectContext" connectionString="server=<serverIP>; user id=<userid>; password=<password>; database=<dbName>; pooling=false; Persist Security Info=True " providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Here is the code that I have throws error

```
MyProjectContext db = new MyProjectContext();
            Person user = (from q in db. Persons
                            where q.PersonId == 1
                            select q).First();
```

I get the following Error

```
{"An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct."}

{"The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string."}
```

If I use MYsql with model first it works with Connector I Have which is 6.6.4.0
I already have a DB created manually, so i do not want to have Initialization for Creating DB. this Code first gives me more control of the classes than having to run the tt file and update the edmx file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the EF power Tools that did Reverse Eng inner code first generation, wihc worked. it produced the same Connection string but different DBcontext class with statict method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put in `name=` at all, as long as the project that contains `MyProjectContext` also contains that connection string in its App.Config file:

```
public MyProjectContext() : base("MyProjectContext")
```

Comment: i tried removing the name that didn't help. still getting same error

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the App.config of the project that contains your MyProjectContext file also has that exact same connection string?

Comment: i have same connection string in app.config of my DAO project and my web.config of web project.